# Why am I receiving "invalid 'right' arguement" when using cut()

Tags: r

I created a function in R that creates deciles (or any n-tile) based on a volume metric as opposed to observation counts.

```
User_Decile <- function(x,n,Output = " "){
    require(dplyr)
    df <- data_frame(index = seq_along(x),value = x)
    x_sum <- sum(df$value)
    x_ranges <- x_sum/n
    df <- df %>% arrange(value)
    df$cumsum <- cumsum(df$value)
    df$bins <- cut(df$cumsum, breaks = floor(seq(0, x_sum, x_ranges)),
                   right = T,
                   include.lowest = T,
                   labels = as.integer(seq(1,n,1)))

if(Output == "Summary"){
    df <- df %>% group_by(bins)
    return(df %>% summarise(Lower_Bound = min(value),
           Upper_Bound = max(value) - 1,
           Value_sum = sum(value)))}

else {
    df <- df %>% arrange(index)
    return(as.numeric(df$bins))}
}
```

(`x` is a vector of numbers, `n` is the number of bins/-tiles to group the data into, `Output=` specifies if you want a summary of the bounds/data or the actual data itself.)

It previous worked well within a program I created to segment some data, but I just tried to use the function again for the first time in a couple months and I'm getting:

```
Error in .bincode(x, breaks, right, included.lowest) :
  invalid 'right' argument
```

According to the error, the issue is with the 'right' argument in the cut() function.  As far as I know, the `right=` argument is boolean and only takes T or F values.  I've tried both, but neither seems to work.

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue, or can recommend another function in place of `cut()`?

Answer (score 1):

`?TRUE` states that:

> TRUE and FALSE are reserved words denoting logical constants in the R
>   language, whereas T and F are global variables whose initial values
>   set to these.

It appears that `T` is being interpreted as something else here. You should always use `TRUE` to be on the safe side.